# Onenote files unavailable

Tags: 8.1, onedrive, onenote

My Onenote files on phone and on Onedrive disappeared.

I had access to them this morning. I did some internet banking and then an hour later tried to access a file - at this point I noted that all my Onenote files are no longer available.

Comment: Have you checked your files on Onedrive usin browser or desktop client ?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Jubayer/Rowland, Thank you for getting back to me on this matter. I should mention that all the other files I have on Onedrive are still there. Only the main Onenote file is missing. There is a single Onenote file but the main one is gone. Can Windows phone to a file-restore? No error messages/i can check desktop on Monday.

Comment: Update: On the desktop browser I did find the 29 Mb file however it cannot be downloaded to my Windowsphone. Even on the desktop it cannot be opened. Strange times!

Comment: That sounds like your file may have been corrupted somhow, if you can't also open it from your desktop PC.

Comment: Thanks Roland. I think I must try work on it a bit when I next have access to a dektop..